# Tubeless issues: New UST (Mavic Comete pro) with Pirelli Cinturato velo but lots of leaking at the bead

Tags: tubeless, sealant

I have been trying to get the Pirelli cunturato velo's (26C) to mount on the Mavic Comete pro (19c inner rim width) which as UST I have not used rim tape. The installation was tough, and I did have to use leavers to get the tire on, but tried to be careful and am pretty sure I went no where near the tape. I pumped initially without sealant, and then when I heard the tires mount in the bead with a loud pop, and checked everything was seated corrected, I added sealant and pumped up. I have given the tires a good shake, let them lie down on either side too to try and get the sealant to the places it was needed. I used 10ml more than on the bottle as they are a new system and when the tires are fully deflated I can feel the sealant in there.

But after 24 hours and multiple pumps and trying to get the sealant to where it's needed, they are still leaking very badly. I tested with water and there is around 5 or 6 places on one of the rims where air is shooting out, one or two places on the other.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this tire but one thing that can happen with really light tires is that they take more sealant than they're "supposed" to before air stops bleeding through in random spots in the sidewalls. If that's where your leaks are, that could be the solution. If it's leaking at the bead area and only at the bead area on a rim that's supposed to not need tape, that's a deeper problem. The only thing I could think to do then would be build it up with tape anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response @NathanKnutson. It is only around the bead, but it actually does seem to perhaps be getting better in the last few hours. I've taken to pumping to 60PSI, putting the wheel parallel to the ground and giving it a twirl and then letting it rest.  I can see the sealant leaking out, and I wasn't seeing that before so perhaps this is a good sign and an indication that hte sealant had not gotten high enough and each time I do it it seems to hold the pressure a little better.

Comment: The tires though are, if anything, the opposite of of light. Quite thick and I bought them as this is my first time using tubeless and despite the rave reviews from a lot of people, I'm still nervous. This current trouble isn't helping either :D

Comment: What sealant? Also don't just assume that adding a tape layer is something that shouldn't be done here. Sometimes one has to go from one to two layers of tape to get the seal working as it should. There's nothing magical about this rim.

Comment: It's MucOff No puncture no hassle. It seemed to be rated well, but it is definitely sealing now better. What does slightly worry me is the leaks were around the bead, and you said above that if leaking at the bead area it's concerning, something I've seen repeated else where, and I've seen others say they're running with no sealant with no issue. Do you think this is something I should worry about?

Comment: I have used that product and I loathe it.

Comment: That tire won't be able to run without sealant. Most won't; that's a good thing. To be honest I've seen the Muc-off sealant work badly enough often enough that I can't help but suspect that's the entire problem.